# Tikz picture code

Tags: graphics, paragraphs, typography, graphs, includegraphics

[image]

How to draw this figure in tikz picture. can anybody give provide me its code.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Have a look at similar questions and to create a starting point, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/494487/123129

Answer (score 3):

try this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,fit,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{Point/.style={draw,fill,circle=0.5mm,inner sep=0.5mm}}

\node[Point, label={[right,name={L11}]:$U_{1,1}$}](u11){};
\node[Point,below=1em of u11, label={[right,name=L12]:$U_{1,2}$}](u12){};
\node[Point,below=1em of u12, label={[right,name=L13]:$U_{1,3}$}](u13){};
\node[fit=(u11)(u12)(u13)(L11)(L12)(L13),ellipse,draw,label={$U1$}](u1){};


\node[Point, below=6em of u13,label={[right,name={L21}]:$U_{2,1}$}](u21){};
\node[Point,below=1em of u21, label={[right,name=L22]:$U_{2,2}$}](u22){};
\node[Point,below=1em of u22, label={[right,name=L23]:$U_{2,3}$}](u23){};
\node[fit=(u21)(u22)(u23)(L21)(L22)(L23),ellipse,draw,label={$U2$}](u2){};
\node[fit=(u1)(u2),draw, ellipse,label=U]{};

\begin{scope}[xshift=15em]

\node[Point, label={[right,name={L11}]:$V_{1,1}$}](v11){};
\node[Point,below=1em of v11, label={[right,name=L12]:$V_{1,2}$}](v12){};
\node[Point,below=1em of v12, label={[right,name=L13]:$V_{1,3}$}](v13){};
\node[Point,below=1em of v13, label={[right,name=L14]:$V_{1,4}$}](v14){};
\node[fit=(v11)(v12)(v13)(v14)(L11)(L12)(L13)(L14),ellipse,draw,label={$V1$}](v1){};


\node[Point, below=8em of v13,label={[right,name={L21}]:$V_{2,1}$}](v21){};
\node[Point,below=1em of v21, label={[right,name=L22]:$V_{2,2}$}](v22){};
\node[Point,below=1em of v22, label={[right,name=L23]:$V_{2,3}$}](v23){};
\node[fit=(v21)(v22)(v23)(L21)(L22)(L23),ellipse,draw,label={$V2$}](v2){};
\node[fit=(v1)(v2),draw, ellipse,label=V]{};
\end{scope}

\draw (u1) -- (v12);
\draw (u2) -- (v12);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]